# Bootstrap Tooltip NOT A FUNCTION when jQuery DataTables is initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, tooltip

Maybe the answer's here and I'm just not seeing it, so any assistance would be most welcome.  I have a table, that I'm loading jQuery DataTables onto, plus I'm using Bootstrap, and some of the spans IN the td's have Bootstrap tooltips.  The tooltips work fine, just by themselves, since I have the init script in the footer - but when I add the dataTables basic init script, suddenly I get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Here's what I have:

***HTML5***

```
<table id="resources" class="hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Thumbnail</th>
                <th>Instrument</th>
                <th>Share</th>
                <th>Resources</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Thumbnail</th>
                <th>Instrument</th>
                <th>Share</th>
                <th>Resources</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Video</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="resource-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Title of Video</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="resource-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="Title of Video" class="img-responsive img-resource"></a></td>
                <td>Insutrment</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareModal">Share <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                <td><span class="fa-stack fa-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Video Resource"><i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#resources").DataTable();
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
          container : 'body'
     });
});
```

I'm loading in the following libraries:

- jQuery - 3.2.1
- Bootstrap - 3.3.7
- DataTables - 1.10.15

Comment: That's an ancient version of jQuery. Maybe it wasn't added until a newer version?

Comment: Let me change the question, updating my version of jQuery did NOT resolve the issue

Comment: Just had the same problem, turned out I was including JQuery twice - once manually and then again in the datatables cdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#resources").DataTable();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



<table id="resources" class="hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr title="Tooltip Test">
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Thumbnail</th>
      <th>Instrument</th>
      <th>Share</th>
      <th>Resources</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Thumbnail</th>
      <th>Instrument</th>
      <th>Share</th>
      <th>Resources</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Video</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="resource-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Title of Video</a></td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="resource-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="Title of Video" class="img-responsive img-resource"></a>
      </td>
      <td>Insutrment</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareModal">Share <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
      <td><span class="fa-stack fa-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Video Resource"><i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap's tooltip, not Jquery-UI.  I'm not even loading in jquery-ui to the page.

Comment: Run my updated snippet after bringing in all your resources. Seems to work.

Comment: huh... I must have had something in the wrong order, I just reordered by CSS and JS library link codes, and now it works fine.